# Remove optionMenu from Fragment Toolbar

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-optionsmenu

I am having an `optionMenu` at my `MainActivity` inflated inside `onCreateOptionsMenu` of my `MainActivity` and there are some fragments which are inflated inside the `MainActivity` which have their own `Toolbars`. But the problem is that the `OptionMenu` is also visible on the `Toolbars` inside the fragments. I don't want the fragments to have the `OptionMenu` for Fragments toolbar

Comment: can you attach a screenshot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`setHasOptionsMenu(true)` in your fragment `onCreate();`

in `onCreateOptionsMenu` inflate your fragment menu and remove `MainActivity` by using `menu.removeItem(R.id.menu_id_to_be_removed);` in `onPrepareOptionsMenu`

Comment: it think menu.remove is a sensible option let me try

Answer (score 1):

You can remove/hide overflow icon from toolbar by following the below steps

1. In your fragment where you want to hide it.

   ```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(
        LayoutInflater inflater,
        ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState
   ) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
   View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_create_group,container,false);
   setHasOptionsMenu(true);
   }
   ```
2. override **"onPrepareOptionsMenu"**. Like below

   ```
   @Override
   public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(@NonNull Menu menu) {
    menu.clear();
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

> For the fragment you don't want onCreateOptionsMenu include following code in those fragments

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setHasOptionsMenu(false);
}
```

Comment: the fragments have their own optionMenu but its mixing up the menu from the activity and the fragment

Comment: for example in activity their is a notifications menuItem icon and in fragments on optionMenu i am inflating another menu with search icon.. but the fragment contains both notification and search icon

Comment: try with  setHasOptionsMenu(true); for fragments who has their own menu. it should override Activity's onCreateOptionsMenu